# List retainAll exception

Tags: java, list, exception, sublist

I wanted to test how to get intersection between two lists, here is my code :

```
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20);
        List<Integer> list2 = list.subList(2, 5);

        System.out.println(list.subList(2, 5));
        System.out.println(list.containsAll(list.subList(2, 5)));
        System.out.println(list.retainAll(list2));
```

This produces :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.retainAll(Unknown Source)
    at gov.noaa.nhc.App.main(App.java:48)
```

But I'm not doing any removes. Why is this producing exception?

**Update I :**

Using :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
List<Integer> list2 = list.subList(2, 5);
```

Produces :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Since list2 is backed by list1, removing items from list1 will cause this exception. Finally working version :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(18, 19, 20);
```

or

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(18, 19, 20));
```

or

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
 List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(2, 5));
```

Thanks for your answers everyone.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use `Arrays.asList`, you get a list backed by the actual array passed in with restricted functionality.  If you want a fully modifiable list you have to create a new list.  For example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(16, 17, 18, 19, 20));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(2, 5));
list.retainAll(list2);
System.out.println(list);
// result: [18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the `retainAll` operation is not supported by this collection.

Comment: Using your example I get Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: That's because you used `subList()` function. `list2` is backed by `list`. The `retainAll` function uses an iterator to delete the non intersecting values - this causes `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can read about `Iterator` and concurrent modification on Javadocs.

Comment: 1 solution is: `List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(2, 5));`

Comment: Updated answer to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Why that result? I supposed  result  [ ]. retainAll: Retains only the elements in this list(list) that are contained in the specified collection(list2).

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) says, the `List.retainAll()` method

> Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, **removes** from this list all the elements that are not contained in the specified collection. [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 1):

[retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) does remove items from the list it is invoked on.

Answer (score 0):

retainAll does remove all elements which are not in the given list.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation also says that retainAll throws UnsupportedOperationException when List implementation does not support this method.